# Functions through & from a point

Tags: functions

Suppose there are two functions *f(x)* & *g(x)* and there is a point *A*. One of the given functions passes via A and the other function originates at A; I am interested to find out which function passes via A and which originates at A.
Is there a method / way to find this out without knowing the Domain & Range of the functions ?

Comment: What does it mean for a function to originate at a point?  The usual definition of a function does not have an order to the points of the graph.  I suppose you could ask that $A$ be on the boundary of the domain, but that is against what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to continuous real-valued functions $f$ and $g$, since you specify that one function (say $f(x)$) passes through A, that would imply there exist values for both $f(x+\epsilon)$ and $f(x-\epsilon)$, whereas $g(x)$ would only be defined for either $g(x+\epsilon)$ or $g(x-\epsilon)$ but not both, for some small number $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer...